# Combining two column transformations in a single mutate() function in dplyr 1.0.0

Tags: r, dplyr

I need to first transform a subset of character columns into numeric columns using mutate and then round those numeric columns to two decimal places.

Here's some toy data.

```
library(dplyr)

# dataset made up of all character columns
d <- data.frame(point = c("point = 1", "point = 2", "point = 3"),
                b = as.character(c(1.0004, 3.4567, 4.6789)),
                c = as.character(c(10.231, 11.345, 18.987)),
                stringsAsFactors = F)
str(d)

# 'data.frame': 3 obs. of  3 variables:
# $ point: chr  "point = 1" "point = 2" "point = 3"
# $ b    : chr  "1.0004" "3.4567" "4.6789"
# $ c    : chr  "10.231" "11.345" "18.987"
```

Now we can use mutate to transform the last two columns to numeric

```
d %>%
  mutate(across(!contains("point"), as.numeric)) -> d2

str(d2)

# 'data.frame': 3 obs. of  3 variables:
# $ point: chr  "point = 1" "point = 2" "point = 3"
# $ b    : num  1 3.46 4.68
# $ c    : num  10.2 11.3 19
```

Now to round the recently-transformed numeric columns to two decimal places

```
d2 %>% mutate(across(where(is.numeric), round, 2))

#       point    b     c
# 1 point = 1 1.00 10.23
# 2 point = 2 3.46 11.35
# 3 point = 3 4.68 18.99
```

What I want to know is **can the two transformations be performed inside a single mutate() call?**

Comment: Try it and see. `d %>% mutate(across(!contains("point"), as.numeric), across(where(is.numeric), round, 2))` works for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
d %>%
  mutate(across(!contains("point"), ~round(as.numeric(.x), 2)))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `purrr::compose()` to nest functions calls

```
d %>%
  mutate( across( !contains( "point" ), 
                  purrr::compose( round, as.numeric )))
```

Comment: Thanks @HubertL, but how do you round to say 2 places?

Comment: you then have to use the formula shortcut like `purrr::compose(~round(., digits=2),as.numeric)`